# Insert variavel decimal no firebird

Tags: c#, sql, firebird, sql-insert, decimal

Estou fazendo um Insert em banco de dados Firebird em um campo ValorUnitario(decimal), porem nao aparece as casas decimais na tabela.

Codigo em C# :

```
public decimal ValorUnitario { get; set; }

produto.ValorUnitario = Convert.ToDecimal(5.50);
string sql = $"INSERT INTO PRODUTO(VALOR_UNITARIO)VALUES('{produto.ValorUnitario}');
```

No banco de dados insere ValorUnitario = 55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema não está plenamente esclarecido no questionamento pois não consta a estrutura das tabelas envolvida.

Mais informações sobre os tipos de dados numéricos do Firebird podem ser acessados em: [Fixed-Point Data Types](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-fixedtypes.html)

Crie uma tabela de teste com a seguinte DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE (
ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
NOME   VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
VALOR  DECIMAL(15,2));
```

Insera um registro com o comando:

```
insert into teste(id, nome, valor) values(101,'teste', 4.52);
commit;
```

Em teste realizado, com os comandos executados pelo ibexpert o resultado foi o esperado.

Answer (score 1):

O problema foi solucionado fazendo uma alteração na estrutura da tabela, antes meu campo VALOR_UNITARIO era um decimal(18,0) e fiz uma alteração mudando a estrutura do campo para decimal(18,2).

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUTO ALTER COLUMN VALOR_UNITARIO TYPE DECIMAL(18,2); – @Edison
```

Answer (score 0):

Não Trabalho com C# mas está utilizando produto.ValorUnitario para converter o valor e entidade.ValorUnitario para concatenar a String SQL. Se isto for o correto, ok, mas confere o conteúdo da variável SQL, que contem o comando a ser executado, possivelmente ai já vai encontrar o problema. Para Firebird o formato do decimal deve ser separado por "." ou seja 5.5

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54256/discussion-on-answer-by-edison-de-brito-insert-variavel-decimal-no-firebird)